# handwriting recognition for isolated arabic

Tags: android, ocr, arabic, tesseract, leptonica

I develop an application in Android OS for recognizing handwritten isolated arabic character using Tesseract OCR. I have tried it but in some case Tesseract cannot recognize handwritten isolated arabic character with connected character, So I want to ask :

1.Is there any character recognizer that can make my application recognize connected characters more accurate?

2.I heard about Leptonica as a lib for image processing in Tesseract, is that enough to increase the precision in recognizing arabic in Tesseract ? Or is there any lib for image processing that can make recognize process more accurate?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood your question, but I think that it's a logic result what you got. because the connected characters shapes will differ from the same character when they disconnected. I suggest you to train tesseract on the shapes of the characters when they are connected

please put some illustrating image to let me able helping you